# Find $\int ((x^2-a^2)\cos x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find $\int ((x^2-a^2)\cos x)dx$

I need to find this indefinate integral without using technology.

I tried integration by parts, making 
$$u=x^2-a^2$$
$$g'=\cos x$$
$$u'=2x-2a\cdot a'$$
$$g=\sin x$$

to then get the equation 
$$\int ((x^2-a^2)\cos x)dx=-\sin (x)(x^2-a^2)-\int(2x-2a\cdot a')\cos (x)dx$$

I dont know how to proceed from here. Did I find $u'$ incorrectly?

How (or even can you) find $\int(2x-2a\cdot a')\cos (x)dx$, seeing as theres two different terms in there?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is $a$ a function of $x$?

Comment: If $a$ is a constant (which I think is safe to assume) $a' = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that integration by parts is a good way to approach this problem!  And you made good choices with $u$ and $g$!  However, I suspect that $a$ is a constant (i.e. it doesn't depend at all on $x$).  So when you take the derivative of $u$, you should get $u' = 2x$.  This simplifies your integration to $$\int (x^2 - a^2)\cos(x) \, dx = \sin(x) (x^2 - a^2) - \int 2x \sin(x) \, dx$$ and you can solve this last integral with another application of integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Integrating by parts $\int x\cos x\,dx$ (again) you can obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\int (x^2-a^2)\cos(x)dx=$$
$$\int x^2\cos(x)dx-a^2\int \cos(x)dx$$

twice by parts
$$\int x^2\cos(x)dx=$$

$$x^2\sin(x)-2\int x\sin(x)dx=$$

$$x^2\sin(x)+2x\cos(x)-2\int \cos(x)dx$$

$$\int a^2\cos(x)dx=a^2\sin(x)+C$$